# how to query two tables from database and show the result in a single row using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have two tables One for users and the other for project listing

My problem is that i want to display each project(from project_table)and email belonging to user who listed the project(from user_table) on a single row

The project_table has a row for user_id(i.e id from user_table that identifies the user who posted the project)

here's my view(project_view):
I this case im displaying data from project_table but i want to display email for a particular user from user_table

```
<?php 
 foreach($query as $row)
 { 
?>
    <p> <?echo $row->pro_name ?></p>
<p> <?echo $row->duration ?></p>
<p> <?echo $row->budget ?></p>
<p>User email will be displayed here</p>
<?
 }
```

my model:

```
function get_projects()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('project_table');
    return $query->result();
}
```

my controller:

```
function show_projects()
{
    $data['query']=$this->project_model->get_projects();
    $this->load->view('project_view', $data);
}
```

Any ideas on how to implement this will be much appreciated

Comment: This is done-able via joins or nested foreach(). I will try demonstrate both (in answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try `join` this -

1) Model

```
function get_projects()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('project_table');
    $this->db->join('user_table', 'project_table.user_id = user_table.id');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

2) Controller

```
$data['user_project'] = $this->project_model->get_projects();
$this->load->view($view, $data);
```

3) View

```
foreach($user_project as $row)
{ 
    echo "<p>" .$row->pro_name. "</p>";
    echo "<p>" .$row->duration. "</p>";
    echo "<p>" .$row->budget. "</p>";
    echo "<p>" .$row->email. "</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use joined query in your model

```
function get_projects()
{

    $query =$this->db->select('p.*,u.email')
                 ->from('project_table p')
                 ->join('user_table u','p.user_id = u.id')
                 ->get();
     return $query->result();

}
```

And in your view you can do so

```
<?php
foreach($query as $row)
{ 
?>
    <p> <?php echo $row->pro_name; ?></p>
    <p> <?php echo $row->duration; ?></p>
    <p> <?php echo $row->budget; ?></p>
    <p><?php  echo $row->email;?></p>

<?php
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite controller and model function to allow for a *user* parameter:

```
function get_projects($user=null)
{
    if ($user == null){
        $query = $this->db->get('project_table');
    }else{
        $query = $this>db->get('project_table')->where('user_id',$user);
    }
        return $query->result();
}


function show_projects($user)
{
    $data['query']=$this->project_model->get_projects($user);
    $this->load->view('project_view', $data);
}
```

Now you can call your controller with a user parameter

```
http://..../show_user/1
```

Answer (score 0):

1st approach is JOINs

```
$this->db->select('project_table.* as project, user.id as user_id, user.email as email')
         ->from('project_table')
         ->join('user', 'project.id = user_id');
$result = $this->db->get();
```

---

2nd not recommended

```
function get_projects()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('project_table');
    return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : FALSE;
}

function get_email($id = FALSE) {
    if ($id === FALSE) return FALSE;
    $query = $this->db->get_where('user', array('user_id' => $id));
    return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : FALSE;
}
```

somewhere in controller...

```
if (!$projects = $this->model->get_projects()) {

    foreach ($projects as $key => $project) {
        # code...
        $projects[$key]->user_email = $this->model->get_email($project->user_id);
    }

    //projects is now with user_email field
    $this->load->view()...

} else {

    //no data recieved
    redirect(); //redirect to default_controller
}
```